# Requests from nuxtjs auth middleware to backend don't go trough?

Tags: frontend, nuxt.js, middleware, pinia

I know that he title of this question is not very good however there is nothing descriptive of what i am facing, so i have a frontend on nuxtjs and a backend on expressjs i can login and everything i can store the user in the store created with pinia:

```
import { defineStore } from "pinia";

interface User {
    id: string,
    username: string,
    email: string,
}

export const useAuthStore = defineStore({
  id: "auth",
  state: () => ({
    authUser: null as User | null,
  }),
  getters: {
    user: (state) => state.authUser,
  },
  actions: {
    async getUser() {
        const resp = await fetch('http://localhost:8080/identity', {
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
        })

        if (resp.ok) {
            this.authUser = await resp.json()
        } else {
            throw resp.status
        }
    }
  }
});
```

This works for getting the user when on a page, but when i tried to use this with a middleware:

```
import { useAuthStore } from "~/stores/user";

export default defineNuxtRouteMiddleware((to, from) => {
  const authStore = useAuthStore();
  authStore.getUser();
  if (authStore.user != null) {
    return navigateTo("/");
  }
});
```

It does all sorts of weirdness like getting a random cors error then not getting it even though i literally modified nothing, the request doesn't even get past the try block that i have in the handler in express so this means that there is something very wrong and this has lead me to the point where i am no longer getting the fetch error in my console. user remains null and the request still doesn't get past the try block and thus we are not redirected to '/'.